# Can't make use of workflow environment variable in github action from marketplace (through build matrix)

Tags: mongodb, github-actions

I'm trying to make use of a workflow environment variable in a marketplace action, using a build matrix but it's not working for some reason.

I basically want to define the database versions just once to avoid repeating them in multiple place in my workflow.

Here's my workflow (minimal reproducible example):

```
name: dummy
on:
  pull_request:
env:
  MONGODB_3_6: 3.6.13
  MONGODB_4_0: 4.0.13

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        MONGODB: [$MONGODB_4_0, $MONGODB_3_6]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Start MongoDB
      uses: supercharge/mongodb-github-action@1.3.0
      with:
        mongodb-version: ${{ matrix.MONGODB }}
```

And it's failing with the error below, as if the `MONGODB_4_0` wasn't defined.
[image]

Interesting fact, without the strategy matrix, I'm able to make it work using the `env` context([doc](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#env-context)):

```
- name: Start MongoDB
  uses: supercharge/mongodb-github-action@1.3.0
  with:
    mongodb-version: ${{ env.MONGODB_4_0 }}
```

Comment: `MONGODB: [${MONGODB_4_0}, ${MONGODB_3_6}]`?

Comment: Unfortunately not, github complains immediately with "Invalid workflow file (error in yaml syntax)"

Comment: What about `MONGODB: [${{MONGODB_4_0}}, ${{MONGODB_3_6}}]`?

Comment: same output, github immediatly fails with an error syntax https://github.com/bagerard/test_github_actions/actions/runs/366743069

Comment: I simply _hate_ github for this, I've used circleci before and this is a breeze other there.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**: according tests and comments, I think matrix can't take environment variables and/or dynamic values.

so the best way will be :

```yaml
matrix:
  MONGODB: [3.6.13, 4.0.13]
```

---

As @max said you can use a variable for your workflow, so I guess your matrix should be wrong, maybe you can try like that :

```yaml
MONGODB: [${{ env.MONGODB_4_0 }}, ${{ env.MONGODB_3_6 }}]
```

You have only one job (test) so you can define your env variables at the job level also.
Variables will be accessible for all the job :

```yaml
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      MONGODB_3_6: 3.6.13
      MONGODB_4_0: 4.0.13
```

For further information : [github doc](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenv)

Comment: `env` can be defined at the workflow level: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#env

Comment: Output is unfortunately exactly the same if I define the env at job level instead of workflow level (https://github.com/bagerard/test_github_actions/actions/runs/366748668/workflow)

Comment: And using ${{ env.MONGODB_4_0 }} in the matrix isn't working either (syntax error) https://github.com/bagerard/test_github_actions/actions/runs/366764502
The problem seems to be a combination of env var + build matrix

Comment: Well sound very weird, I think they didn't take the fact of the matrix can be dynamic as you set specific values. Maybe set directly version on the array for the matrix should be fine. Is this really need to have env variables for that ?

Comment: Matrices don't work with enviroment variables in Github Actions.